# Redirecting traffic to Tomcat context path in Kubernetes service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jira, nginx-ingress

In a scenario where I set the context path of the Tomcat server by changing the `server.xml` file like this:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Context path="${catalinaContextPath}" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
        <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
            factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
        <Manager pathname=""/>
        <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="120" />
    </Context>

</Host>
```

If `catalinaContextPath` is set to `/my/new/context` The server will start up in the Pod with the URL: `localhost:8080/my/new/context`. How do I change the service so that it sends all traffic arriving on service port 80 to container path `<pod_ip>:8080/my/new/context`

This is my current service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
namespace: jira
name: jira
spec:
selector:
    app: jira
    component: jira
ports:
- protocol: TCP
  name: serverport
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8080
```

My use case is, I am deploying this [this JIRA docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/dchevell/jira-software) in a Pod and I set the context path using the environment variable `CATALINA_CONTEXT_PATH` as specified in [this documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/dchevell/jira-software). **When I try to access it, it results in a 404. I assume this is because traffic is being redirected to `<pod_ip>:8080` and nothing is running on `<pod_ip>:8080` since tomcat has started up on `<pod_ip>:8080/my/new/context`**

EDIT: 
This is the `ingress.yaml` I am using:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.app }}
  name: jira-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dev/jira(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: jira
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /prod/jira(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: jira
          servicePort: 80
```

Whenever I visit `myhost/dev/jira` I need it to go to my JIRA instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application *"real"* root is *`/my/new/context`*, you can rewrite every incoming request matching the *`/dev/jira`* URI using [Nginx's `AppRoot`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite):

> If the Application Root is exposed in a different path and needs to be redirected, set the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root to redirect requests for /.

If you're using this approach, there is no need to use capture groups with `rewrite-target`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.app }}
  name: jira-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /my/new/context
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /dev/jira(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: jira
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /prod/jira(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: jira
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with services... I would strongly suggest using Ingress paths.

see here: [Can a host be redirected to a service path in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307264/can-a-host-be-redirected-to-a-service-path-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Hi I attached my ingress to the question. How should my ingress be changed to meet my requirement? Thanks